# Get base64 in good old IE11 (Not using promises)

Tags: javascript, promise, internet-explorer-11

I have already implemented a method to get a base64 from a file using promises. Which runs fine in edge, chrome and firefox.

Problem is that I also have to make it work in internet explorer 11. Which does not like promises I found out. Problem is that IE11 is using ES5 and Promises came in ES6. (Please correct me if i'm wrong)

So I have 3 options as I see it.

- Try to rewrite the code using callbacks so that IE11 knows the syntax.
- Using babel (Which I haven't tried but read it was an option)
- Using bluebirdjs (Which also I haven't tried but read it was an option)

**Which is the best option for me?**

Here are my code I need to change:

```
$('#fileselected').change(function (e) {
    var fileList = document.getElementById('fileselected').files;
    var file = fileList[0]; // User can only choose one file at a time

    getBase64(file).then(
        data => {
            var fileObj = { name: file.name, base64: data };
            postFilesToUpload.push(fileObj); // Collecting the files, if user wants to add multiple
        }
    );

    $("#postfilesadded").append("<li><h5>" + file.name + "</h5></li>"); // Show the user which files he have selected to upload
});
```

This method is using another method which I need to change:

```
function getBase64(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = () => resolve(reader.result);
    reader.onerror = error => reject(error);
  });
}
```

Comment: you can check also https://github.com/taylorhakes/promise-polyfill

Comment: So use a promise polyfill or use babel?

Comment: You can try to choose the babel to convert your ES6 code to ES5. Ref: https://babeljs.io/

Comment: I already tried babel, but when pasting in the code, it does not rewrite the function "then". Internet explorer does not recognize that.

Comment: I see that when I try to paste above code in Babel. Did you made a test with the polifil suggested by the @Margon? If you have a small code than you can try to rewrite it in ES5 to support IE.